# Add LocationProvider Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I configure locationProvider on my routes ? I'm using angular 5.

I don't find documentation about it.

```
const appRoutes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/example/example', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'example', children: [
    {path: ':example', component: example}
  ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {
        // enableTracing: true, // <-- debugging purposes only
      })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem with what you've shown is. The answer is probably in https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

locationProvider is used in AngularJS but not in Angular 2/5.

You have to use Router, RouterModule and RouterOutlet instead. Refer to https://angular.io/guide/router to get more informations.

For example, to change location you can use in JS

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

or in HTML

```
<button [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</button>
```

You can also catch some events like "NavigationStart", "NavigationEnd", "NavigationError"

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use -

```
<a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
```

this will naviagate to home component

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to Angular 5. Angular JS and Angular are entirely different.
Angular 5, there is no location provider available in Angular 2/4/5.

Please go with the following documentation
[Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

user Router Link as below
From Template

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" fragment="education">
link to user component
</a>
```

from typescript

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```